# knp paginator bundle filtration settings

Tags: php, paginator, knppaginator, knppaginatorbundle

I use this bundle in symfony 4, my filtering code looks like this

```
{{ knp_pagination_filter(paginator, {
                    't.code': 'Code'
                }) }}
```

as well as my settings file in the 
***/conf/ directory***

```
knp_paginator:
    page_range:                 5          # default page range used in pagination control
    default_options:
        page_name:              page       # page query parameter name
        sort_field_name:        sort       # sort field query parameter name
        sort_direction_name:    direction  # sort direction query parameter name
        distinct:               true       # ensure distinct results, useful when ORM queries are using GROUP BY statements
        filter_field_name: filterField
        filter_value_name: filterValue
    template:
        pagination: '@KnpPaginator/Pagination/twitter_bootstrap_v4_pagination.html.twig'
        sortable: '@KnpPaginator/Pagination/sortable_link.html.twig' # sort link template
        filtration: '@KnpPaginator/Pagination/filtration.html.twig'  # filters template
```

No one faced with the fact that filtering is very rigidly tied to the value of the filter? for example:
And the base has the values ​​"AppleJuice" and "Apple" when typing in the filter field "Apple", I do not see the value "AppleJuice", only "Apple"

***where I can set the filter type WHERE '%' + LOWER (param) + '%' LIKE LOWER (item.code)***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exit, write your SQL query in your table service file

Comment: Could you please add more details about implementation and how that's better to build a form to pass in request all the existing sorting parameters along with own params for filtering? Just to have the ability to sort and filter (with LIKE) at the same time using knp_paginator.